# How to let Vue3 (Vite) project go through Clash proxy?

Tags: vue.js, proxy, vite

First, I used Clash Mixin and configured hosts so that the *.test domain names pointed to 127.0.0.1.

After testing, I got the Vue2 project (created by vue-cli). Without any proxy configured, I can directly access the API of xxx.test.

However, projects created by Vue3 (Vite) cannot always access xxx.test.

I suspect it's because I configured a cross-domain proxy and /api points to andy.test.

In this case, I would like to ask /api to point to andy.test, but also be able to access andy.test correctly. What should I do?

```
server: {
       host: "0.0.0.0",
       port: viteEnv.VITE_PORT,
       open: viteEnv.VITE_OPEN,
       cors: true,
       // Load proxy configuration from .env.development
       proxy: createProxy(viteEnv.VITE_PROXY)
     },

VITE_PROXY = [["/api","http://andy.test"]]
```

[image]

Comment: The description of the problem is unclear, and so is the code. `VITE_PROXY = [["/api","http://andy.test"]]` - what kind of syntax is that? What is createProxy and why do you expect it to work correctly?

Comment: ```
export function createProxy(list: ProxyList = []) {
  const ret: ProxyTargetList = {};
  for (const [prefix, target] of list) {
    const httpsRE = /^https:\/\//;
    const isHttps = httpsRE.test(target);

    // https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options
    ret[prefix] = {
      target: target,
      changeOrigin: true,
      ws: true,
      rewrite: path => path.replace(new RegExp(`^${prefix}`), ""),
      // https is require secure=false
      ...(isHttps ? { secure: false } : {})
    };
  }
  return ret;
}
```